# Find n with n is natural number and $n^{2}+n+6$ is a cube.

Tags: number-theory

Find n with n is natural number and $n^{2}+n+6$ is a cube.

I have tried to find a module to find The difference but it is not working.

Then I rewrited the equation: $n^{2}+n+6=a^{3}$

$(n-1)(n+2)=(a-2)(a^{2}+2a+4)$

But i have no idea for next step.

Comment: Do you need all $n$ or just one? Because $n=1$ works.

Comment: The cubes of 2, 6, 8, 12, 236 can be obtained  -- not sure if there are more.

Comment: @EdPegg, there are no others for $n<10^8$.

Comment: Let $x=(2n+1)$ hence $x^2+23=4a^3$ which again if we multiply it by $16$ you will have $y^2=b^3-23\cdot 16$ this is [Mordel equation](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/ross2008/mordell.pdf)